# Fragment Back button pressed which method is called or how to call user defined function

Tags: android, android-fragments, backbone-events

I have one ActionbarSherlock Activity and 3 Actionbar Tab.The second tab having two Fragments(A and B). The Fragment "A" having the list calendar and Fragment "B" having the Task adding functionalities.When i click the Fragment "A" list calendar items it will be go to the Fragment "B". Then I add some task in fragment "B" and then press back button to redirect Fragment "A" fine.My problem is when i back to the Fragment "A" from Fragment "B" which method is called and also i update the task details when back to the Fragment "A".Thanks...

ActionbarActivityclass:

> When i select the second Actionbar Tab that having two fragments ListCalendarFragment and TaskFragment.First I add both fragments.Then I hide the TaskFragment and show only ListCalendarFragmnet.

```
        TaskFragment()fragmentTask = new TaskFragment();
        ListCalendarFragment fragmentListCalendar = new ListCalendarFragment();
        fragmentrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentrans.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentListCalendar);
        fragmentrans.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentTask);
        fragmentrans.hide(fragmentTask);
        fragmentrans.commit();
```

> When i click the list calendar item it will call one listener that can be used to show Task Fragment as well as hide the List Calendar Fragment.

```
SherlockFragmentActivity activity = getSherlockActivity();
                if (activity instanceof ListItemClickListener) {

                    ((ListItemClickListener)activity).onListClick();
                }
```

> ListItemClickListener: Interface

```
public interface ListItemClickListener {
public void onListClick();
}
```

ActionbarActivityclass implements ListItemClickListener.
This functionality show the Task calendar and hide the List Calendar.

```
@Override
public void onListClick() {

    fragmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentrans = fragmanager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentrans.hide(fragmentListCalendar);
    fragmentrans.show(fragmentTask);
    fragmentrans.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentrans.commit();

}
```

> My problem is when i back to the List Calendar by clicking the back button at that time which lifecycle method is called or how to call the user defined method in the List Calendar Fragment.Because i need to refresh the List Calendar Adapter in ListCalendar Fragment.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. Here's how I solved a similar problem:

Make an interface for Fragment B like this:

```
public interface FragmentBListener {
    public void onBackButtonPressed();
}
```

Then, instantiate it in Fragment B (up above onCreateView where you instantiate widgets, etc):

```
FragmentBListener mCallback;
```

Then, in your Fragment B, whenever you want to go back, or cancel or whatever, you call:

```
mCallback.onBackButtonPressed();
```

The interface is, of course, implemented in your main activity (or whichever activity you choose), so there should be a method there like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackButtonPressed() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBackButtonPressed()");    

    // Do something, e.g. reload Fragment A
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but how it is working.When i call the back button how the interface automatically called.